# How to connect to Spark master in Swarm mode from host

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, pyspark, docker-swarm

I want to run a python application on a Spark cluster, but my application is not inside the master container necessarily. The following is my compose yaml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  spark-master:
    image: bde2020/spark-master
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          [node.hostname == master]
    environment:
      - INIT_DAEMON_STEP=setup_spark
    ports:
      - '6080:8080'
      - '6077:7077'
      - '6040:4040'
  spark-worker-1:
    image: bde2020/spark-worker
    depends_on:
      - 'spark-master'
    environment:
      - 'SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077'
    ports:
      - '6081:8081'
      - '6041:4040'
```

When I create a stack and run these two containers on my Swarm cluster, and run my python application with the following SparkSession configuration, I receive `connection refused` error.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("spark://PRIVATE_HOST_IP:6077") \
    .appName("Spark Swarm") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

On the other hand when I run those containers in normal mode with `docker-compose up`, the same python application with the same SparkSession configuration works like a charm. Obviously, it is not desirable since I want to have the possibility of scaling up and down. Therefore I am looking for a way to run my application in Swarm mode.

The strange thing about my issue is that I am pretty sure that port mapping is done correctly because after setting up the stack, I am able to connect to Spark UI via `6080` port, which is the port that I have mapped to `Spark:8080`.

Another point is that I have successfully connected to other containers like Cassandra and Kafka via the same approach (mapping the serving ports of those containers to host ports, and connecting to the set ports on host), but the same avenue is not working for Spark container.

Comment: how do you run the stack ? did you configure the swarm Network already?

Comment: @LinPy I use the default network of Docker Swarm mode which is `overlay` network. I also tried the approach in which I explicitly defined the overlay network, but it didn't work either. I noticed that normal mode of Docker container is on `bridge` network, but it is asserted that for connecting multiple nodes in Swarm cluster, the network must be `overlay`.

Comment: yes , did you follow this ? https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-overlay/

Comment: @LinPy yes I defined a new attachable overlay network. Then, I determined this network as `external` network in my compose file and defined this network as the network of my Spark service. Actually, I did not try to customize default `ingress` network. Do you think that might be the issue? It doesn't seem promising since I am already able to connect to other containers like Cassandra with the default `ingress` network.

Comment: did you see the scope is swarm when you type `docker network ls` ?

Comment: @LinPy yes, I observed that.